# Datos NULL en Delphi 7

Tags: delphi

Si el texto de un edit está `Null` mostrar mensaje para que se llenen los datos requeridos de lo contrario ejecutar el código.
Eso es lo que necesito.

Comment: Tendrías que explicar exactamente qué quieres decir con NULL. Un edit puede estar vacío (que no es lo mismo que estar a NULL), sobre todo si ese campo está relacionado de alguna manera con valores de la Base de Datos.
Pero todo esto es suponer...
Deberías dedicarle un poco más de tiempo a la pregunta para obtener mejores respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que verificar que el texto de tu edit no esté vacio para ejecutar el código. De lo contrario, mostrar un mensaje para que el usuario llene los datos:

```
if Trim(edt1.Text) <> '' then
  // tu codigo
else
    showmessage('Por favor introduzca un valor');
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio @Javier. Por favor agrega más información a la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias Luiggi. Ahora con descripción.

Answer (score 1):

Si es un TEdit la respuesta de Javier es la correcta, pero si hablás de null te debés estar refiriendo a un DBedit enlazado a datos de un TDataSet.

```
if not VarIsNull(DataSet[FieldName]) then
  // tu codigo
else
    showmessage('Por favor introduzca un valor');
```